# swiftui what`s meaning this crash report?

Tags: crash, swiftui, tableview

Only crash on iphone11 device.

--->>>  4   UIKitCore                       0x19c04f808 -[UITableView _Bug_Detected_In_Client_Of_UITableView_Invalid_Number_Of_Sections:] + 200 (UITableView.m:2402)

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x197d9496c __exceptionPreprocess + 224 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x197aad028 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x197c914fc +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 100 (NSException.m:146)
3   Foundation                      0x1980d2690 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 132 (NSException.m:231)
4   UIKitCore                       0x19c04f808 -[UITableView _Bug_Detected_In_Client_Of_UITableView_Invalid_Number_Of_Sections:] + 200 (UITableView.m:2402)
5   UIKitCore                       0x19c04ec98 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 11024 (UITableView.m:2303)
6   UIKitCore                       0x19c066824 -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 128 (UITableView.m:7403)
7   UIKitCore                       0x19c0669f8 -[UITableView _performBatchUpdates:withContext:completion:] + 280 (UITableView.m:7429)
8   UIKitCore                       0x19c066b68 -[UITableView performBatchUpdates:completion:] + 120 (UITableView.m:7440)
9   SwiftUI                         0x1cf171cc0 $s7SwiftUI25UpdateCoalescingTableView33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLC19performBatchUpdates_... + 452 (ListCore_PhoneTV.swift:71)
10  SwiftUI                         0x1cf171e74 $s7SwiftUI25UpdateCoalescingTableView33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLC19performBatchUpdates_... + 184 (<compiler-generated>:0)
11  SwiftUI                         0x1cf174578 $s7SwiftUI19ListCoreCoordinator33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLC17updateUITableView_4from2to... + 1812 (ListCore_PhoneTV.swift:318)
12  SwiftUI                         0x1cf172c44 $s7SwiftUI9_ListCore33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLV12updateUIView_7contextyAA12TableWrappe... + 880 (ListCore_PhoneTV.swift:219)
13  SwiftUI                         0x1cf4fecec $s7SwiftUI32PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptor33_19642D833A8FE469B137699ED1426762LLV06updateD8Provi... + 340 (UIViewRepresentable.swift:258)
14  SwiftUI                         0x1cf1e402c $s7SwiftUI17PlatformViewChild33_A513612C07DFA438E70B9FA90719B40DLLV6update7contexty14AttributeGra... + 2424 (PlatformViewRepresentable.swift:296)
15  SwiftUI                         0x1cf1de77c $s7SwiftUI17PlatformViewChild33_A513612C07DFA438E70B9FA90719B40DLLV6update7contexty14AttributeGra... + 308 (PlatformViewRepresentable.swift:232)
16  SwiftUI                         0x1cf1e5380 $s7SwiftUI17PlatformViewChild33_A513612C07DFA438E70B9FA90719B40DLLVyxG14AttributeGraph07UntypedM0... + 40 (<compiler-generated>:0)
17  AttributeGraph                  0x1c343d9c0 0x1c3421000 + 117184
18  AttributeGraph                  0x1c3424e9c 0x1c3421000 + 16028
19  AttributeGraph                  0x1c3425164 0x1c3421000 + 16740
20  AttributeGraph                  0x1c342a130 0x1c3421000 + 37168
21  SwiftUI                         0x1cf0a7afc $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC14runTransaction33_D63C4EB7F2B205694B6515509E76E98BLL2inySo10AGGraphRefa_tF + 224 (ViewGraph.swift:712)
22  SwiftUI                         0x1cf0a78a4 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC17flushTransactionsyyFySo10AGGraphRefaXEfU_ + 240 (ViewGraph.swift:608)
23  SwiftUI                         0x1cf0a7524 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC17flushTransactionsyyF + 188 (<compiler-generated>:0)
24  SwiftUI                         0x1cf3e13fc $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtFyyXEfU_yyXEfU_ + 1632 (ViewRendererHost.swift:156)
25  SwiftUI                         0x1cf3e0b98 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtFyyXEfU_ + 624 (ViewRendererHost.swift:137)
26  SwiftUI                         0x1cf3d5f74 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtF + 456 (ViewRendererHost.swift:124)
27  SwiftUI                         0x1cf5517d8 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewC14layoutSubviewsyyF + 172 (UIHostingView.swift:1312)
28  SwiftUI                         0x1cf551808 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewC14layoutSubviewsyyFTo + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
29  UIKitCore                       0x19c3488b0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2156 (UIView.m:17028)
30  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x197aa8a4c -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 68 (NSObject.mm:2182)
31  QuartzCore                      0x19e95e55c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 292 (CALayer.mm:9627)
32  QuartzCore                      0x19e95e9ac CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 484 (CALayer.mm:9501)
33  QuartzCore                      0x19e9711bc CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 140 (CALayer.mm:2461)
34  QuartzCore                      0x19e8b5b00 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 308 (CAContextInternal.mm:1992)
35  QuartzCore                      0x19e8e0910 CA::Transaction::commit() + 684 (CATransactionInternal.mm:438)
36  QuartzCore                      0x19e8e14e4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 96 (CATransactionInternal.mm:888)
37  CoreFoundation                  0x197d0f524 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36 (CFRunLoop.c:1758)
38  CoreFoundation                  0x197d0a1c4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 420 (CFRunLoop.c:1868)
39  CoreFoundation                  0x197d0a774 __CFRunLoopRun + 1292 (CFRunLoop.c:2910)
40  CoreFoundation                  0x197d09f40 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
41  GraphicsServices                0x1a1f9a534 GSEventRunModal + 108 (GSEvent.c:2246)
42  UIKitCore                       0x19be95580 UIApplicationMain + 1940 (UIApplication.m:4773)
43  MyHairNote                      0x102605944 main + 68 (firebase_session.swift:16)
44  libdyld.dylib                   0x197b88e18 start + 4
```

Comment: The meaning is as described "Invalid Number Of Sections"... but more interesting is the reason, and to find it your have to provide code to reproduce or analyse?

Comment: Please share any relevant code as a  [example] See also [ask].